# Quand utiliser le passé du subjonctif et quand utiliser l'imparfait du subjonctif ?

Tags: subjonctif, temps-grammatical

Quelle est la concordance du temps du passé du subjonctif et de l'imparfait du subjonctif ?

Par exemple:

Je voulais qu'il soit resté, ou je voulais qu'il restât ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Naturellement j'aurais proposé le présent : *« Je voulais qu'il reste »*.

Il semble que les trois temps sont corrects, mais le sens est sensiblement différent, comme le fait judicieusement remarquer l'[article Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif_imparfait). Il faut noter que le subjonctif imparfait n'est pratiquement plus utilisé, aussi il peut choquer à l'oreille.

Essayons quelques exemples, avec un verbe différent pour éviter les non-sens :

> *« Je priais qu'il reste »*

L'action de **prier est antérieure** ou simultanée à l'action de rester ou non ; on sous-entend qu'il **n'est pas resté**.

> *« Je priais qu'il restât »*

L'action de **prier est antérieure** ou simultanée à l'action de rester ou non ; on sous-entend qu'il **est resté**.

> *« Je priais qu'il soit resté »*

L'action de **rester ou non est antérieure** à l'action de prier : *« Apprenant qu'il y avait eu une tempête, je priais qu'il soit resté à la maison »*.

> *« Je prie qu'il soit resté »*

L'action de **rester ou non est antérieure** à l'action de prier, qui elle se situe dans le présent.

P.S. : n'hésitez pas à discuter les nuances le sens que j'attribue à ces formulations. En tout cas c'est une question qui mérite un vote. :)

Comment: Ah trop compliqué .. mais je vous remercie pour cette bonne explication. *je vais vite chercher dans le grevisse*

Comment: @WilliamChen: quel est votre langue maternelle ? Je peux essayer de rendre les exemples plus accessibles ou proposer une traduction si nécessaire.

Comment: anglais -- merci :)

Answer (score 2):

> Je voulais qu'il soit resté.

Est bancal à mon oreille parce que le moment avant lequel il aurait dû rester n'est pas précisé. C'est dans le passé comme l'expression du désir, mais pas situé par rapport à lui. On pourrait compléter

> Je voulais qu'il soit resté toute la matinée à la maison quand j'arrivais à midi.

Tandis qu'avec

> Je voulais qu'il restât.

Le désir et l'action désirée sont simultanés.